# Build Corda application with maven

Tags: maven, corda

Anyone use corda with maven? all the sample are with gradle. i need to use the Cordform Common  plugin for deploy nodes but i did't found any example in maven.

Thanks

Whit gradle Cordform Common plugin it' possible to specify the deployNodes task 
 and i need the same thing with manven:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    networkMap "O=Controller,L=London,C=GB"
    node {
        name "O=Controller,L=London,C=GB"
        advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating"]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcPort 10003
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Please clarify your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can depend on Cordform common in maven with these coordinates

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.corda.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>cordform-common</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Make sure to use the correct version, (`1.0.2` for Corda V2. You can find all versions [here](https://bintray.com/r3/corda/cordform-common)).

As for deploy nodes - I believe you are referring to a task that is in training materials and examples for Corda (eg. [here](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V2/build.gradle)). This is a task within Gradle using a Gradle plugin. It is not available in Maven.

You either must use Gradle to be able to use the `Cordformation` plugin (which `deployNodes` depends on) or write your own Maven plugin to do the same (I am unaware of any existing Maven plugins for Corda projects).

Comment: So  it's not possible to do the same things with maven.

Comment: At least not that I'm aware of. If someone has made Maven plugins for Corda that do this they haven't advertised it well. You can always write plugins that do something similar. Also check out the "[DemoBench](https://www.corda.net/downloads/)" that comes with Corda. It allows you to create an environment similar to Cordformation but with a GUI instead of a build system (though that might not be what you need).